# how to take specific string with getdate function in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have one crm application. i want to store conversions date and specific time at which time that thread created that to show. how ever i have also one `[datetime]` column but time is not correct. event though this time part should be default from sql. how ever i want this time part is accurate and how i implement this. is that way to store acuurate time part from sql.

is that way to store time part from getdate function of sql.

for more reference i put table

```
Inquiry_id   varchar(50)    
Inquiry_subject  varchar(50)    
Service_id   numeric(18, 0) 
Priority_id  numeric(18, 0) 
User_id          varchar(50)    
Status_id    numeric(18, 0)
body             varchar(1024)
Email_Address    varchar(50)    
IsDisplay    bit    
IsRead           bit
IsReplied    bit    
TimeStamp   datetime    
Activity_start_time datetime    
Activity_expire_time    datetime
```

please help me..

Comment: What's wrong about it? How are you setting the value?

Comment: you have a datetime column but it is not correct, it should be correct. Sorry, but this sounds like the average enduser telling me the report is incorrect, it should be correct, so fix it.
Can you please eleborate on what you mean with "correct", and what you mean with "incorrect"?

Comment: for example i want to view this massage posted on [created_date] at [time]...

Comment: You might be overthinking this.  Storing getdate gives you access to both the date and time components anytime you want.  Storing just the time part does not change your ability to get the time, but it takes away your ability to get the date.  Also relevent is that sql server 2005 does not have date and time datatypes.  Your only option would be to store the time as a string, but that would be exceptionally unwise.

Comment: i just want to display date part and time part separetly...

Comment: ok can i get like string like [date_part]at[time_part] from sql getdate function. is that way to do with Convert function of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display your DateTime columns as Date and separate Time columns, do this in a SELECT statement (or in a view)

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VarChar(20), Activity_Start_Time, 108) AS ActivityStartTime,
  CONVERT(VarChar(30), Activity_Start_Time, 101) AS ActivityStartDateUS
FROM YourExampleTableAbove
```

This will produce a result like

```
ActivityStartTime   ActivityStartDateUS
-----------------   -------------------
08:10:27            4/23/2013
15:58:40            4/29/2013
```

For more options, read about the Convert() function for TSQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: i just want to create string like [ActivityStartDateUS]'at'[ActivityStartTime] is that possible.

Comment: Yes. SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(30), Activity_Start_Time, 101) + ' at ' + CONVERT(VarChar(20), Activity_Start_Time, 108) AS ActivityStart FROM YourExampleTableAbove